# NodeJS: Static imports possible?

Tags: node.js, static-import

**Question in short:**

Is there a way to statically import functions of another JS file in NodeJS? (As the static-import of Java?)

**Example of what I'd like to do:**

I have a file `m1.js` which contains functions:

```
function add(x,y) { return x + y }
exports.add = add
```

Then I have a file `app.js` which imports `m1.js`:

```
m1 = require('./m1')
var result = m1.add(3,4)
```

Now, what I'd like to do is to import the functions of `m1.js` such that i can call them, without having to prefix the calls with `m1.*`:

```
m1 = require('./m1')
var result = add(3,4)  // instead of m1.add(3,4)
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I've tried the following, in the file `m1.js`:

```
function add(x,y) { return x + y }
exports.static = function(scope) { scope.add = add }
```

and tried to import `m1.js` in `app.js` as follows but it wasn't able to find `add(x,y)`:

```
require('./m1').static(this)
var result = add(3,4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close with your attempt. The one small change you have to make is replace `this` with `global` when `static` is called:

```
require('./m1').static(global)
var result = add(3,4)
```

From the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

> #### global
>
> - {Object} The global namespace object.
>
> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope `var something` will define a global variable. In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; `var something` inside a Node module will be local to that module.

Comment: @ndrizza Thats a novel solution, but keep in mind that usage of globals is accessible across the entire app and is not good IMO :-)